# Need to know webclient download method run in UI thread

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have used the web client method to download images using a background worker in my wp7 app. I came to know the webclient method usually run in the UI thread by default. So now there is a confusion that wheather the webclient run in the backround thread or UI thread in the app even if it is mention inside the background worker class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execution of a `WebClient` request will run on the thread it is called on, unless it has a Async suffix at the end of it's method name. (For example `DownloadData(Uri)` will run on the same thread as the call. `DownloadDataAsync(Uri)` will run on a new background thread)

If you're using a `BackgroundWorker` to call your WebClient requests it will not be executed on the UI thread (Both using the `Download` and `DownloadAsync` methods), because `BackgroundWorker` already runs it's code in a background thread in the first place.

EDIT: Looking at your tags, it should be noted that Silverlight (and thereby Windows Phone 7) only supports the Async versions of the `WebClient` calls.

Answer (score 1):

The Webclient async calls will run in a separate thread, but as of WP SDK 7.1, the callback events will be called on the thread that the WebClient was created on. (In WP SDK 7.0 the events were always called on the UI thread).